# Find element containing specific text and certain parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I've searched up and down but cannot find what I am looking for.

I am pulling data using a pretty basic jQuery.ajax call:

```
function retrieveFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xxxxx/taskdata.xml",
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        return true;
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            parseXML(data);
        },

        error: function() {
        console.log("Error retrieving XML");
        }
    });
}
```

The XML is really simple:

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <title>Refresh Sports page code base</title>
        <id>15276645606996729654</id>
        <owners>
            <owner>
                bfranklin
            </owner>
            <owner>
                bting
            </owner>
        </owners>
    </task>
    <task>
        <title>Security audit for college sports pages</title>
        <id>12019410900674133028</id>
        <owners>
            <owner>
                rgoulet
            </owner>
            <owner>
                bfranklin
            </owner>
        </owners>
    </task>
    <task>
        <title>Fill holes in site monitoring</title>
        <id>828664522750709776</id>
        <owners>
            <owner>
                rgoulet
            </owner>
            <owner>
                dgreene
            </owner>
            <owner>
                lkeene
            </owner>
        </owners>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

What I am trying to do is take a name, say rgoulet, and retrieve the title and/or id of the tasks assigned to him. So the first goal is to search my jQuery object $(data) for any owner element with the text "rgoulet". Next I want to get the title and id directly above it.

I know this has to be possible but I'm stumped. I've seen "parents" but I don't know how to specify. Plus, I have tried a few ways of searching $(data) for every instance of owner with rgoulet but all have ended up in the all-so-descriptive "parse error". :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found the correct `<owner>` containing `'rgoulet'`, use `.closest('task')` to find the nearest parent element of type `<task>`:

```
var $task = $(data).find("owner:contains('rgoulet')").closest('task');
```

Comment: I tried that but it wants to search the entire DOM. How can I limit it to $(data) as passed from my Ajax call? And since rgoulet is owner for multiple tasks, how can I search for all the tasks he is owner on?

Comment: Almost there. I am getting an object. How can I get the text value? I tried: var $task = $(data).find("owner:contains('rgoulet')").closest('task').text();" but that did not work.

Comment: @user You have to decide which text you want, and then traverse to that element. If you want the id, add `.find('id').text()`. If you want the title, add `.find('title').text()`.

Comment: Ahhh stupid mistake. I should have caught that. :) Sorry,I have an infant and get only 3-4 hours of sleep each night. :)

Comment: Could I do something like: $(data).find("label:contains(rgoulet')").closest('task').find('title').text().sort() to sort them by title? I will try that.

Comment: Eh, no dice. Looks like I will need a plugin to sort my results. I was hoping to create my data set with "$(data).find("owner:contains('USERNAME')").closest('task').find('title').text().sort().each(function() {" and in there use closest to get the other details. That way the user could select the sort method.